# Can't 'map' an array in array of objects correctly in reactjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects (here is only one but thats does not matter) in my JSON "dummy" back end.
In each object I have a property "tags" which also contains simple array, let me show you an example

```
[
 {
  "title": "Get up and run",
  "author": "Johnny",
  "tags": ["react", "javascript"]
 }
]
```

I tried to map an array which gave me a result: (see the code)

```
Article title: Get up and run
Writer: Johnny
Tags: reactjavascript
```

but i want to get result like that:

```
Article title: Get up and run
Writer: Johnny
Tags: react javascript (or "react, javascript" or "#react #javascript")
```

it seems I can't map "tag" array and main array of objects correctly same time. :(
can u help me?

```
class Content extends Component {
 state = {
    posts: []
}

componentDidMount () {
    axios.get("json-file.json")
    .then(response => {
            this.setState({posts: response.data.map(post => {
                return post; /*here I get the whole data from dummy 
backend */
            })})
        }
    )
}

render () {
    const post = this.state.posts.map(post => {
        return <Post 
            title={post.title} 
            date={post.date} 
            author={post.author}
            tags={post.tags.map(xTag => {
                return xTag ;
            })} /* I have other Component which correctly renders this... 
 no worries here */
            />
    })

    return (
        <div>
            {post}
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

I expect the better "map" of array
I try to get result like this

Article title: Get up and run
Writer: Johnny

```
Tags: react javascript (or "react, javascript" or "#react #javascript")
```

instead of

```
Tags: reactjavascript
```

or

```
Tags: ["react", "javascript"] (it was the worst version :)(its fixed ;) ) )
```

I want to map an array of objects and 'tags' array at same time and correctly,

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing `tags={post.tags.map(xTag => { return xTag ; })}` is equivalent to `tags={post.tags}`. So the relevant code that affects the final formatting is in Post component. So could either do `tags.join(', ')` or `tags.map(t => '#'+t).join(' ')`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate component for tag and style it. 
Then rewrite this line:

```
tags={post.tags.map(xTag => {
    return <Tag>{xTag}</Tag>;  // or <Tag content={xTag} />
})}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert your tags array into a string there are several options depending on your desired format:

Using a simple join your formatting is limited: (You can pass in characters which will be appended after every entry e.g `.join(' ')` for only spaces)

```
post.tags.join() // Returns 'react,javascript'
```

Using the `reduce` function you have further control over how your string will be formatted:

```
post.tags.reduce((string, tag) => string += `${tag} `, '')
```

To change the format just edit the string which is attached `${tag}`